# Что за концепт friend class?

Tags: java, терминология, abap

Добрый день. Перешел на новую работу, работа заключается в интеграции с системой SAP ERP. Там есть понятие Friend class. Есть ли его аналог в Java?

*Сколько программирую, ещё такого понятия не встречал.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`friend` - дружественный из арсенала C++.

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

по сути класс или метод, который имеет доступ к приватным и защищенным членам класса.

В Java такого понятия нет.

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ )